# Kinect application including a Unity 3D avatar

Tags: wpf, unity-game-engine, kinect

I am currently working on a Kinect application, its helps the user to do his workout and follow his progress, using Kinect and an avatar that's supposed to be made on unity 3D .
{The avatar replaces the real coch, user follows his coach ( avatar ) and Kinect helps returning an activity report depending on the user's mouvement tracked }

I actually cant find from where to start ! I found that unity/WPF projects integration is possible . BUT I COULDNT FOUND A CLEAR ROADMAP for how is this going to happen.

I am mainly wondering about :

1. making my ( avatar + animations ) on unity :
   Will this be done only on unity, or modeling is done using 3DMax for exemple and animations are hold up with unity..
2. Integratin on a WPF prject :
   which step is this one ? when should the integration happen
3. AND MAINLY ! how may I continue working on that with the Kinect sensor..
4. finally, as I dont know which steps to follow I can not estimate the project's time !
   how much time does such applications take to developp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate Kinect with Unity I can recommend for you [this tool](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/7747) from Asset Store.

In my opinion Unity is not the best tool for making 3D objects you should use for example 3DMax to make an avatar and then import it to the Unity.

WPF and Unity are different frameworks and I will not use them both in the same project, you should consider using one of them, these tools have different use cases.

For learning Kinect SDK please visit for example offical forums [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/kinectsdk).

To estimate this project you should firstly get to know more about those technologies.